# How to perform a hot repair of a functioning, but limping rootfs with the switch_root command and a blank partition?

Tags: mount, init-script, fsck, root-filesystem

I have an extreme edge case that I may never see again, but I'd like to be prepared. I have an embedded system (u-boot) whose primary disk has 4 partitions. One of the partitions is the rootfs (`ext4`) and unfortunately it is `rw`. The `ext4` does a great job of handling rough interactions, but I saw an issue with it for the first time today. The mount was still functional but `systemd-fsck-root.service` failed and indicated it required a CTRL-D to continue and told me to run `fsck`.

```
systemd-fsck[1130]: /dev/mmcblk1p4: Superblock last mount time is in the future.
systemd-fsck[1130]:         (by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set)
systemd-fsck[1130]: /dev/mmcblk1p4 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
systemd-fsck[1130]: /dev/mmcblk1p4: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
systemd-fsck[1130]: /dev/mmcblk1p4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
systemd-fsck[1130]:         (i.e., without -a or -p options)
systemd-fsck[1130]: fsck failed with error code 4.
systemd-fsck[1130]: Running request emergency.target/start/replace
```

My kernel does not have `initramfs` or a backup partition. All I have is:

- A mostly unused partition next to the rootfs one
- the `switch_root` command

My plan is the following:

1. Copy the basic files I need to run linux on a different partition
2. Copy `fsck` and anything else I need to repair the rootfs to the empty partition
3. Jump over to the other partition with `switch_root`
4. Umount the primary rootfs and perform the fsck fix
5. `reboot` and the bootloader should just poitn back to the fixed primary

The main things I don't know are:

- Will this work?
- What are the basic files I need for `#1`? Do I need to include loaded kernel modules or will those stay in the kernel?
- What would a very simple init script look like to facilitate the `switch_root` jump?

Comment: You should read the WARNING in switch_root 's man page first. Although the code appears to only erase ramfs or tmpfs ( https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/-/blob/v2.36.1/sys-utils/switch_root.c#L187 ) are you sure of your version ( https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/-/commit/07de470e437f204e3d40b8b0a85f57c1978ff9ed )?

Comment: I don't have a ramfs and tmpfs does not have an critical data so that is fine